# python: break list into pieces when an empty entry is found

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a list that looks like:

```
[
  [],
  ['blah','blah'],
  ['a','b'],
  [],
  ['abc','2'],
  ['ff','a'],
  ['test','a'],
  [],
  ['123','1'],
  []
]
```

How do I break this list into list of lists when it encounters an empty item

so list[0] would have :

```
['blah','blah']
['a','b']
```

list[1] would have:

```
['abc','2']
['ff','a']
['test','a']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Maybe there's a more clever solution, but it seems that a `for item in list_of_lists: ...` would be a good way to start.

Comment: Does this "list" actually start with a blank?

Comment: @larsks : That's what I am using right now..but it doesn't seem so elegant

Comment: @rayray84: yes it starts with a blank, a blank entry denotes a separate group in the data i am looking at

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), using bool as the key:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(l, key=bool) if k]
```

Demo:

```
In [22]: from itertools import groupby


In [23]: lst = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(l,key=bool) if k]

In [24]: lst[1]
Out[24]: [['abc', '2'], ['ff', 'a'], ['test', 'a']]

In [25]: lst[0]
Out[25]: [['blah', 'blah'], ['a', 'b']]
```

`k` will be False for each empty list and True for all non-empty lists.

```
In [26]: bool([])
Out[26]: False

In [27]: bool([1])
Out[27]: True

In [28]: bool([1,1,3])
Out[28]: True
```